# Django Rest Error "raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % str(exc))"

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, django-views, microsoft-teams

```
def comp_data(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        data =JSONParser().parse(request)
        print(data)
```

This is my views.py, I was hoping that the data posted will be printed in cmd.
The data is posted from microsoft-teams so to figure out how the JSON looks I tried this.
I need to know the format how the data is posted from teams to get into the format my backend API accepts.

Comment: What this request contains? Teams library provide you data in json format only, you can parse, Please take a look at [python sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python) code for more information

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: The data type received was apparently of the type bytes, then I did decode('utf8') did some string manipulations made it to a dictionary(in the fomat which my JSON accpets) and converted it into a JSON then.

Comment: So is this resolved or you need more assist on this?

Comment: Yes this is resolved, I have seen somewhere that data entered in teams cards will be posted to the target URL only in JSON format that is why I tried collecting my data with JSON parser(hence the above code and question) but later I when I checked the type of the data that was collected It was in bytes. So what is the default data type in which data collected in the cards posted to the target URL?